# Документация по user API telegram

Tags: php, telegram, api

В сети много информации по API для ботов Telegram, но я не могу найти информацию желательно на русском по API для пользователей.
Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: application **programming** interface — по определению предназначено для программистов, а не для пользователей.

Comment: Вам по какой библиотеке документация нужна? aiogram?

Comment: Для PHP-> сейчас изучаю MadelineProto
Хочу понять как вообще работать с API telegram